# Из TemplateResponse получить файл на отправку на почту

Tags: python, django

```py
def render_payroll(self, form, data):
    response = TemplateResponse(
        self.request,
        'payroll/payroll.html',
        context={'data': data},
    )
    # Нажата кнопка скачать
    if 'payroll_action_download' in form.data:
        response['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8"
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="payroll.xls"'
        return response
    # Отображаем
    elif 'payroll_action_show' in form.data:
        return response
    # Отправляем по почте письмо с вложением
    else:
        text_message = render_to_string('payroll/send.html',{'data': data})
        subject_message = f'Расчетный листок за {data["month_rus"]} {data["t_year"]}'
        email = EmailMessage(subject_message, text_message,"andrey.korolkov@it-ps.ru",["axxel123@rambler.ru"])
        email.content_subtype = 'html'

        **email.attach(filename='payroll.xlsx', content=bytes(str(response.rendered_content), encoding = 'utf-8'), mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')**

        email.send(fail_silently=False)
        messages.success(self.request, "Расчётный лист отправлен на почтовый адрес")
        return redirect(reverse('payslip'))
```

Подскажите, как отправить файл на почту?
Пока приходит только xlsx файл, но внутри html

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение сам)
До отправки нужно вызвать:

```
response.render()
```